# How to create strongly typed aliasses in D?

Tags: types, d

How do I create a strongly types alias in D? Something like:

```
alias euro = uint;
alias dollar = uint;

euro toEur(dollar pd) { ... }
dollar toDollar(euro pe) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A strongly typed alias is actually a new type, so just use a plain struct:

```
struct euro {
     uint amount;
}
```

If you want it to implicitly convert to and from uint, you can also add `alias amount this;`, but that weakens the typing so you might not want to.

Comment: I already considered this, but wouldn't that require me to do euro.amount every time?

Comment: Not with `alias amount this`, then it will implicitly use `amount` every time you ask for something `euro` itself doesn't do. So you can pass it as a uint, assign it from a uint (unless you overload opAssign and change that), etc.

Comment: How does that weaken the typing? I just tried a testcase and it doesn't accept a uint to be mixed with a euro.

Comment: alias this works kinda like inheritance, with it the euro can be implicitly converted to its "base type" of uint. If you also had an opAssign or ctor on `dollar` that accepted uint, it would then let dollar = euro compile, euro converts to uint which then runs that constructor, potentially breaking the system. So I don't mean this as a bad thing, just something to be aware of and handle appropriate for your case.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is [Typedef](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.Typedef), which basically does what Adam suggests.